# Woocommerce Email show HTML source code

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, html-email

I updated my Woocommerce to version 5.6.0 but since that update the emails send by Woocommerce (invoice/order updates etc) will be send as HTML-source code despite it has to send a designed template. I didn't change anything on code, but maybe someone has a fix for this.

Comment: I think you should ask WooCommerce directly, e.g. start at https://developer.woocommerce.com/ They'll know what specifically changed in 5.6.0.

Comment: It's also worth working out if you're now sending an HTML body as plain text or if you're sending the HTML content as HTML, you're just esc_html()ing it once too many. You can then trace through the code to work out where this is going wrong.

Comment: Another important detail is how you're sending email: using the built-in SMTP - via your host's SMTP servers? - or using a third-party mail plugin such as Sendgrid or Postmark or SES.

Comment: It would also be a useful data point to roll back WooCommerce to 5.5.1 and see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was indeed in the settings from my SMTP host (Elastic Email). They also had a update but the 'Auto' function doesn't work properly. You have to change it to html/text and Woocommerce emails will work again